# TypeError: The "config.server" property is required and must be of type string

Tags: node.js, sql-server

Facing the error

> Database Connection Failed! Bad Config:  TypeError: The "config.server" property is required and must be of type string.
>       at new Connection (D:\License Generation\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:87:13)
>       at base.Promise (D:\License Generation\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:237:23)
>       at new Promise ()
>       at ConnectionPool._poolCreate (D:\License Generation\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:195:12)
>       at ConnectionPool._connect (D:\License Generation\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:245:10)
>       at PromiseLibrary (D:\License Generation\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:220:19)
>       at new Promise ()
>       at ConnectionPool.connect (D:\License Generation\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:219:12)
>       at Object. (D:\License Generation\dbConfig.js:6:2)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)

Configuration File

```
//Database Configuration
const dbconfiguration = {
    server: 'xyz', 
    user: 'fdf',
    password: 'safgfg',
    database: 'License_Keys',
    port: 1433 
};
module.exports = dbconfiguration;
```

```
const sqlInstance = require('mssql');
const configFile = require('./app.config');

//connect to your database
const poolPromise = new sqlInstance.ConnectionPool(configFile.dbconfiguration)
.connect()
.then(pool => {
    console.log('Connected to MSSQL')
    return pool
})
.catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err))

module.exports = poolPromise;
```

Comment: It's recommended to not expose your db credentials and to use secrets. One way is with `dotenv` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and to work properly add `import 'dotenv/config'` at the beginning of your app in most cases it's in app.js or index.js.

Answer (score 1):

Use directly required `configFile`, as you are exporting a single const variable object from that file, you don't need to access it like `configFile.dbconfiguration`

This should work,

```
sqlInstance.ConnectionPool(configFile)
```

Note: To clear confusion, you can export DB configuration like this also,

```
//Database Configuration
module.exports = {
    server: 'xyz', 
    user: 'fdf',
    password: 'safgfg',
    database: 'License_Keys',
    port: 1433 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the "configuration" menu on your azure app service page and supply all the environment variables under "Application Settings". Under "General Settings", ensure that "npm run start" is included to enable your application to run smoothly.